# Naming the clusters of leaflet by unigue names like A, B,C instead of numbers

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have been trying to name the clusters of leaflet by unique name, can any one give the solution for this ?

Context: I have some location pointers, where it get clustered into 5, 3, 4, 3 at some zoom level, instead of showing the numbers on clusters, i need to show by unique name like A for 5, B for 3, C for 4, D for 3

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the [custom cluster example](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html), you can think of something along those lines:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
var n = -1;
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
        maxClusterRadius: 120,
        iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
            n++;
            return L.divIcon({ html: alphabet[n], className: 'mycluster', iconSize: L.point(40, 40) });
        },
});
```

It will only work for 26 unique names of course, but you get the idea.